# The Rain Model's eyelids suddenly stopped working, I'm not sure what could be causing it

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, vertex-groups

I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve on my own. I've been working with the Rain character model for a while now and everything's been going good but suddenly out of nowhere the eyelids have stopped moving. I can't think of what setting I could have touched that would cause something like this to happen

[image: This is the eyelids in their default position]

I've gone through all of the cloudRig settings and messed with every single one and yet still nothing is fixing it.

[image: This is the eyelid bones in what should be a closed position]

If anyone has any kind of advise they could give I would be so thankful to you!!

Comment: Does anything else work?

Comment: Hey, yes as far as I can tell every other bone works except the eyelids

Comment: Do the bones and the vertex groups still have the same names, or are the eyelid bones actually controlling a different set of bones via drivers?

Comment: Well the bone is called ACT-Eyelid_Upper.L and the vertex groups it effects are DEF-Eyelid_Top_1-4.L

What I have noticed is that it's actually all the acting bones that aren't working right now

Comment: Umm, hmm. Do the bones actually move? Is it possible you’ve disabled the armature modifier?

Comment: The bones were able to move but I never messed with the modifiers to my knowledge! Since the project file was not the most important thing for me to keep around, I've uninstalled and reinstalled the Rain Character project from blender cloud and everything seems to be back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've found out what ended up causing this issue. With the base Rain Character download they come with a bunch of other actions that effect some acting bones on the face. I didn't see the point in having them at the time so I just removed them from the blender file. So far it seems like any modifications to these actions causes issues with base face positions and affect the usability of of the face bones.

----DO NOT MESS WITH THESE SETTINGS----